# EF code first concurrency when web API method accessed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, api, ef-code-first

I have this case. My Web Api method in FileController is accesed by multiple users at same time and some of them try to insert same record at same time. I have check for "if the record exists return error", but as the method is accessed at the same time, the context isn't updated yet, so the record doesn't exist in the database  and is inserted by the two/more threads.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Files/Import")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Import(ImportFileRequest request)
    {
      using (var transactionMgr = managerTransactions.BeginTransaction()) //here BeginTransaction returns context.Database.BeginTransaction()
      {          

       if(!managerTransactions.FilesRepository.FileExists(request.FileName)) 
       {
          File file = new File();
          file.Name = request.FileName;
          //other properties
          managerTransactions.FilesRepository.Add(file);
          managerTransactions.SaveCahnges();
          transactionMgr.Commit();
      }
      else
      { 
         throw new Exception("File exists");  
      }
    }
   }
```

So before Save method two threads have entered the method and added file.Second thread entyered before save is performed on the first thread and two records are added to the context. Then save is performed and two files are added in the database. I can't use TransactionScope because our clients don't want to install this service that has to be installed. I tried using lock object and it seems to work but i do't know if it is a good idea

Comment: Why not add a unique constraint on FileName and catch that exception?

Comment: You should use `Optimistic Concurrency`. Read about it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: You can use a distributed lock mechanism to make sure only one thread can do a job at one time. Or you can give a unique constraint to appropriate field at database level.

Both way you have to choose a unique identifier for your data.